# Getting Device user name

Tags: php, android, html, ios

I designed a system that runs on the internet

I am looking for a way to extract the device that is being used for the system (i.e. tablet or Laptop), I need to extract that tablet's user that is registered on it

I am using PHP and HTML

Thanx

Comment: That data is not available in HTMl or PHP, since it should then be added in the HTTP request header which it is not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646918/get-specific-device-information Take a look at that, next time search please before questioning.

Comment: I think you misread my message.....

Comment: I AM LOOKING FOR THE USER NAME!!! NOT the device name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons.

Moreover, there is no requirement that there be *any* user "registered on it", at least for Android tablets, and so there may not be a "user name" available in the first place.