# Detecting splash page PHP file from non-mobile devices

Tags: php

I am trying to call a php file that opens only if someone clicks a link from a non android or iOS device. Before I only had an error message.

```
if(isset($_GET['appId'])){

$products = getAppDownloadLinks(mysql_string($_GET['appId']));
//do something with this information
if( $iPod || $iPhone || $iPad){
    header('Location: '.$products['ios']);
    exit;
}
else if($Android){
    header('Location: '.$products['android']);
    exit;
}
else{
    //we're not a mobile device.
    $html = file_get_contents('mobileSplash.php');
    }
}
```

Is this an appropriate approach for my final else statement, how do I call that php file to display the splash error page?

Comment: You should check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646918/get-specific-device-information

:)

Comment: I personally would use a library like http://mobiledetect.net/ (in case the algorithm was made from scratch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the User Agent with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in the following way.

```
if(isset($_GET['appId']))
{

     $products = getAppDownloadLinks(mysql_string($_GET['appId']));
     $apple = (preg_match($ua, "/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/") === 1);
     $android = (preg_match($ua, "/(Android)/") === 1);
     //do something with this information
     if($apple)
     {
         header('Location: '.$products['ios']);
         exit;
     }
     elseif($android)
     {
         header('Location: '.$products['android']);
         exit;
     } else
     {
         //we're not a mobile device.
         $html = file_get_contents('mobileSplash.php');
     }
 }
```

This is just what I got out of your Question's Text. You may need to implement it into your Script File or edit it the way you want to have it.

Comment: How would you suggest calling the php file then?

Comment: @BhoffDev after 6 Minutes of work, it is a bit clearer for you. I hope.