# How to get mobile device id in mobile web?

Tags: php, mobile, deviceid

I tried to get device id from mobile through PHP code. Is there any possibility   to get mobile device id from PHP code.

Comment: and **what** exactly have you tried?

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Specific Device Information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646918/get-specific-device-information)

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple solution to use Mobile-detect here: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/

Mobile_Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment. http://mobiledetect.net

Comment: Device id will be like this - "AAAAmPJV_co:APA91bHokL8oQo1zJvbkn_Z7zllNELhu0LTEKz3liuxPhpgjnQdhcmWeB1EfHfR7dyqiTMK4tiT1********************************************"

Comment: All mobiles have one unique id that one i want to get.

Comment: are you talking about the imei?

Answer (score 0):

You will NOT get real device ID in $_SERVER. User agent does not contain that info as well. You cannot access that data just using php or anything else, that is NOT executed on phones.